# How to solve this integral using special functions

Tags: integration, special-functions, gamma-function, beta-function

I came across an integral of this form:

$$\int_{0}^{a}\frac{dx}{(a^{n}-x^{n})^{1/n}}$$
How do I solve this integral?
I tried using this substitution: $x=asin^{2}(x)$ in order to reduce this to a beta form integral, but I a man getting the value $\frac{B(0,1)}{2}$.
This happens to tending towards minus infinity as $B(0,1)=\frac{\Gamma{(0)}\Gamma{(1)}}{\Gamma{(1)}}\rightarrow-\infty$

Any help is appreciated.

**Calculation:**

inserting ansatz, the new integral obtained is: 
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2acos(\theta)sin(\theta)d\theta}{a^{n/n}(1-sin^{2n}(\theta))^{1/n}}$$
This further reduces to:

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{2(cos(\theta))^{-1}(sin(\theta))^{1}d\theta}$$
Comparing this to the standard Beta integral we get p to be 0 and q to be 1 and thus the integral tends towards minus infinity.

Comment: Where is $n$ gone ? Double check your calculation.

Comment: I see that you ignored my comment.

Comment: Nope, I have edited in the calculations.

Comment: Not at all, this is still wrong.

Comment: You mean the answer?

Comment: You forgot $n$ at many places.

Comment: But the n's of a and cos^{2} would cancel

Comment: No, no and no !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53558/discussion-between-naveen-balaji-and-yves-daoust).

Comment: Sorry, no. I have provided an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WLOG, $a=1$.

Then with $x^n=t$,

$$I=\frac1n\int_0^1t^{1/n-1}(1-t)^{-1/n}dt=\frac1n\text{B}\left(\frac1n,1-\frac1n\right)=\frac1n\Gamma\left(\frac1n\right)\Gamma\left(1-\frac1n\right)=\frac{\dfrac\pi n}{\sin\dfrac\pi n}.$$

Comment: A natural question at this point is whether one can obtain this answer directly rather than through special function properties. I suspect the right approach is to use a substitution to map $[0,1]\to [0,\infty)$ and then use a keyhole contour. But this kind of argument can likely be found in a proof of Euler's reflection formula.

Comment: @Semiclassical: the Beta/Gamma relation is usually established through a convolution-like identity involving the Laplace transform. Maybe some simplification can arise for these exponents (?)

Comment: @Semiclassical you an also use a dogbone contour directly on orignial integrand